# T SQL Case Statement with between to Show ALL

Tags: sql, t-sql, case, between

I think I am trying the impossible here but due to my limited knowledge of SQL i need some help to see if there is some thing that i can do.

My issue is that i am working with really bad data and i need to be able to Link and split data and then join.

For example the 2 tables that I am working with

```
TABLE 1
---------
From    To  Street Name
5       10  ADAMS WAY


TABLE 2
-----------
Number
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The output I want is

```
from    To  StreetName  Number
5       10  ADAMS WAY   5
5       10  ADAMS WAY   6
5       10  ADAMS WAY   7
5       10  ADAMS WAY   8
5       10  ADAMS WAY   9
5       10  ADAMS WAY   10
```

So far i have been able to put this together however

```
SELECT *,
CASE
When T1.From = T2.NO
    THEN ???? 'What do i do here'
    END as Table 'What do i do next to get the rows to show'
From
T1
FULL JOIN
Numbers 
ON
T1.AFrom = T2.NO
```

I know this is probably a long shot but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why number 1 to 4 is eliminated in the result?

Comment: Becasue this is actually to do with address data. what i really need is for it to be for each house number to have a full address but what i have is a list that just says from 4 to 10 adams way. this is just a sample i have 174000 adresses to do this for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe:

```
SELECT [from], 
       [to], 
       streetname, 
       number 
FROM   t1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 
                    ON t2.number >= t1.[from] 
                   AND t2.number <= t1.[to]
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae50e/2)

Comment: Hi I have tried but its now pulling up more records than before without

Comment: @user2040295: Sorry, should work now. See the sql-fiddle. The join was the other way around.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly all the answers given work. i just couldnt work out the logic before. as a new user to this site i will try and pass on this knowledge gained. cheers

Answer (score 1):

select * from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
where t2.Number between t1.[From] and t1.[To]

Note that column FROM has to be written like [From], because its a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2
WHERE num >= table1.[from]
AND num <= table1.[to];
```